# Passing data between 2 view controllers in Swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, between

I have 2 view controllers, created separately. It's not navigation controller or other. I've 2 files for each of them: `ViewController.swift`, `SecondViewController.swift`. Second VC is called **audioList**

In 1-st VC I have a button and by clicking on it I'm opening second VC using code

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

})
```

There is an array called `music` in SecondViewController. I want to fill it with elements before code which you can see upper - from 1-st VC.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554620/passing-data-between-view-controllers-swift) one post, others, read about doing it by creating protocol with function which changes data, tried a lot with segues, their performing and prepareFor-functions - but nothing worked.

Help me please with filling `array in 2-nd VC` from `button-click-action in 1-st VC`

**Update**:

In `SecondViewController.swift` I have this code:

```
var music: [String] = ["test"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return music.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = music[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and fill an array on your first view controller.
Then declare an array of the same structure on your second view controller. Then fill it in the segue.

VC1:

```
    var music : [String] = ["Song1", "song2", "Song3"]

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

                            controller.music2 = self.music

                            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        })
```

VC2:

```
    import UIKit

        class audioList: UIViewController {
        var music2 : [String] 

        viewDidLoad()
        {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
controller.music = ["my", "data"]
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That's pity but it does not work too. I've updated my post with code form 2-nd VC, maybe something wrong with printing data to tableView. But after 2-VC opened I see only "test"

Comment: Can you upload your project?