# How to pass value between different storyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift

I use this code to jump between two storyboard and it's success.

```
var sb = UIStoryboard(name: “storyboardbName”, bundle: nil)
var viewctrl = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“a-view”) as! UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewctrl, animated: true)
```

But how can i pass value to the other storyboard?
When i use only one storyboard before,i can set segue to pass value but use to storyboard,there is no segue can set.

Comment: Use global variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, in view controller of second storyboard there is a line `var someString = ""`

Create another variable of the same type in view controller of first stroryboard (from you're executing code you've posted), like `aSomeString = ""`

Set value to `aSomeString` before line `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewctrl, animated: true)` and then set value to variable from destination VC:  `viewctrl.someString = aSomeString`

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012465/passing-data-between-2-view-controllers-in-swift) question, I had the same problem

Comment: Can't use like viewctrl.someString = aSomeString

Comment: Otherwise use static var

Comment: Why? Variables must have same type and declared in bort Vc

Comment: Oh it's my fail, it's can be success. Thx